# NavigationView selected item color

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout, navigationview

i have two layouts that use a drawerLayout and they use the same code for the navigationView, the problem is that one of them changes the color of the selected item while the other doesn't even though it's the same exact code. here is the xml code:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view_passager"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_passager"  />
```

---

and java for the 1st layout:

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.acceuil_passager_item:
            toolbar.setTitle("Accueil");
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_passager, new AcceuilPassagerFragment()).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.profile_item:
            toolbar.setTitle("Profil");
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_passager, new PassagerProfileFragment()).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.historique_voyages_item_pass:
            toolbar.setTitle("Historique des voyages");
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new ListeTrajetsFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.futurs_voyages_item_pass:
            toolbar.setTitle("Futurs voyages");
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_passager, new FutursVoyagesFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.log_out_item_pass:
            Intent intent = new Intent(PassagerActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mAuth.signOut();
            finish();
            Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: " + (mAuth == null));
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

---

and the java code for the 2nd layout :

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.acceuil_item_conducteur:
            setUpToolbar(item);
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_conducteur, new AcceuilConducteurFragment()).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.profile_item_cond:
            setUpToolbar(item);
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_conducteur, new ConducteurProfileFragment()).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.historique_voyages_item_cond:
            setUpToolbar(item);
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_conducteur, new HistoriqueVoyagesFragment()).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.log_out_item_cond:
            Intent intent = new Intent(ConducteurActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mAuth.signOut();
            finish();
            Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: " + (mAuth == null));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

---

[and here is the first layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIBjT.jpg)

[and the 2nd one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5v9J.jpg)

ps: "Profil" is selected in both layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group
    android:id="@+id/menu_grp"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
```

Turned out checkableBehavior = "single" is what made the menu selected item checked and what was missing in my other layout

Answer (score 0):

For navigation view you have to write a color selector like: `nav_view_item_background`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@color/primary" android:state_checked="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

and set `app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_view_item_background"`

For text color you have to same thing. Create a textColor selector and set `app:itemTextColor`

**For Drawer Layout**
`return true` (In Navigation item selection) change the color and selection.

Comment: thank you for your answer and the examples but i already know i can do that, i just wanna know why it works for a layout and doesn't for the other (without including itemTextColor and the others) i wanna know the logic behind that